# Why can't my windows xp latop connect to wireless router from comcast?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, wireless-networking, internet

I have a hp laptop with windows xp.  I have tried to connect to my wireless network, a ubee modem with netgear router, but havent been able to.  I can find my network on the wireless list and try to connect, but nothing happens. After you enter your key, a window pops up saying. . .waiting for network. After a little while the network list reappears and your not connected. Any help?

Comment: I dunno... is it an HP DV 2000, 6000 or 9000 series laptop that is within the x0xx-x4xx model range?  It could be the NVidia chipset issues that spurred a class action suit against NVidia http://fairnvidiasettlement.com/ .  One of the symptoms was a failure of the Mini-PCI slot the wireless card is in.  Of course, without specific information like the model number of your laptop, there's no way I'd know if this was a total shot in the dark, or a bullseye.

Comment: There is not enough info here. I suggest closing it if no more info is given.

Comment: It is an HP Pavilion dv1000 model

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your WEP or WPA key isn't being typed in correctly or isn't using the right WPA standards (WPA vs WPA2, for example). Then again it could be simple interference problems. Things to look for might be cordless phones nearby, fluorescent lighting or even a baby monitor. I've even seen a situation where a HAM radio operator next door was causing WiFi headaches. It's too hard to guess without more details.

Comment: I can get on my network with ipods, xbox and cell phones using the same key